# Any chance of account recovery?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Hi, I lost access to my stack overflow account as I haven't used it in so long, but I have completely forgotten the address of the openID and what it even was I used to sign up/login with since I haven't used it in awhile.

Is there anyway of getting it back at all? I see no recovery options and I suspect I wouldn't be able to use them.

About the best I can do to prove it is me is update the twitter linked to in my profile but I suspect that wouldn't offer enough proof and would have to be highly manual.

Any pointers to a recovery option I've missed would be much appricated!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/49262/sam-phelps is my account in question. I'd really rather not have to start another account. Would I be able to start a new one and have them merged? I remember it having been done in the past.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Send an email to **team@StackOverflow.com** with your information and they should be able to help you.

Comment: Have done. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I guess that's possible. Create a new account and send an email to the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page handing in the IDs of both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If it would be useful, I could e-mail the openid provider (to the e-mail address on the old account). Let me know... Also, if you don't get a prompt reply from team@stackoverflow.com, let me know here.